# php one function alias of another function - how to pass variables through

Tags: php, function

for years my PHP functions (both in classes and outside of classes) have been designed to be flexible and accomplish multiple tasks within the same family of functionality.  Many of these functions are simply written like this:

```
function myFunction(){
$args=func_get_args();
//work with arguments
}
```

BOTTOM LINE: these functions have variable number of arguments passed.

My question is, how would I make an "alias" of a function but pass through the arguments to the namesake function?

P.S. I can develop hacks with a series of default null arguments, or using eval(), but I'd appreciate knowing if there is a better method than this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just try with [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
function myFunction(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    call_user_func_array('otherFunction', $args);
}
```